# Evaluating an Expression using data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df

```
Patient  ID
A        72        
A        SD75
A        74
A        74
B        71
C        72
```

And
I have an expression

```
    exp = '((71+72)*((73+75)+SD75))*((74+76)+SD76))'
```

Now I need to evaluate this expression with ones and zeros if there's a match in the df for each of the three patients A, B , C . 
 A has a match with ID 72, SD75, 74 so the expressions should be

```
    A- '((0+1)*((0+0)+1))*((1+0)+0))'
    B- '((1+0)*((0+0)+0))*((0+0)+0))'
    C- '((0+1)*((0+0)+0))*((0+0)+0))'
```

And My final df_output should look like this

```
Patient  FinalVal
A        1
B        0
C        0
```

The FinalVal can be obtained by eval(exp) after replacing the ID's with 1's and O's


so Far here is where I reached. When I am replacing the ID 75 with 0 the SD75 is becoming SD0 and that's where I am stuck

```
import pandas as pd
import re
exp = '((71+72)*((73+75)+SD75))*((74+76)+SD76))'
mylist = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', exp).split()
distinct_pt = df.Patient.drop_duplicates().dropna()
df_output = pd.DataFrame(distinct_pt)
df_output['Exp'] = exp
for index, row in df_output.iterrows():
  new_df = df[df.Patient == row['Patient']]
  new_dfl = new_df['ID'].tolist()
  #print(new_dfl)
  for j in mylist:
    if j in new_dfl:
      #print(j)
      row['Exp'] = row['Exp'].replace(j,'1')
    else:
      row['Exp'] = row['Exp'].replace(j,'1')
```

Comment: It can.. just like how A falls under 72 as well as c also falls under 72 ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try creating an indicator DataFrame using a [`Series.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) to create indicator columns for each value in the `ID` column, then reduce to a single row per `Patient` via [`groupby max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```py
# Convert to ID columns to binary indicators
indicator_df = df.set_index('Patient')['ID'].str.get_dummies()
# Reduce to 1 row per Patient
indicator_df = indicator_df.groupby(level=0).max()
```

`indicator_df`:

```
         71  72  74  SD75
Patient                  
A         0   1   1     1
B         1   0   0     0
C         0   1   0     0
```

Now we can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) from the expression terms to create missing columns. [`np.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) is used to ensure that duplicate terms in the expression do not result in duplicate columns in `indicator_df` (this can be omitted if it is guaranteed there are no duplicate terms):

```py
exp = '(((71+72)*((73+75)+SD75))*((74+76)+SD76))'
# Extract terms from expression
cols = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', exp).split()
# Convert to ID columns to binary indicators
indicator_df = df.set_index('Patient')['ID'].str.get_dummies()
# Reduce to 1 row per Patient
indicator_df = indicator_df.groupby(level=0).max()
# Ensure All expression terms are present
indicator_df = indicator_df.reindex(
    columns=np.unique(cols),  # prevent duplicate cols
    fill_value=0  # Added cols are filled with 0
)
```

`indicator_df`:

```
         71  72  73  74  75  76  SD75  SD76
Patient                                    
A         0   1   0   1   0   0     1     0
B         1   0   0   0   0   0     0     0
C         0   1   0   0   0   0     0     0
```

Now if we alter the `exp` slightly by surrounding these new columns names with backticks (`) we can use [`DataFrame.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) to compute the expression:

```py
exp = '(((71+72)*((73+75)+SD75))*((74+76)+SD76))'
# Extract terms from expression
cols = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', exp).split()
# create indicator_df (chained)
indicator_df = (
    df.set_index('Patient')['ID']
        .str.get_dummies()
        .groupby(level=0).max()
        .reindex(columns=np.unique(cols), fill_value=0)
)
# Eval the expression and create the resulting DataFrame
result = indicator_df.eval(
    # Add Backticks around columns names
    re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'`\1`', exp)
).reset_index(name='FinalVal')
```

`result`:

```
  Patient  FinalVal
0       A         1
1       B         0
2       C         0
```

---

The backticks are necessary to indicate these values represent column names, and not numeric values:

```py
re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'`\1`', exp)

# (((`71`+`72`)*((`73`+`75`)+`SD75`))*((`74`+`76`)+`SD76`))
```

Notice the difference between 71 with backticks vs without:

```py
# Column '71' + the number 71
pd.DataFrame({'71': [1, 2, 3]}).eval('B = `71` + 71')

   71   B
0   1  72
1   2  73
2   3  74
```

---

Alternatively, the `indicator_df` can be created with a [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```py
exp = '(((71+72)*((73+75)+SD75))*((74+76)+SD76))'
# Extract terms from expression
cols = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', exp).split()
indicator_df = (
    pd.crosstab(df['Patient'], df['ID'])
        .clip(upper=1)  # Restrict upperbound to 1
        .reindex(columns=np.unique(cols), fill_value=0)
)
# Eval the expression and create the resulting DataFrame
result = indicator_df.eval(
    # Add Backticks around columns names
    re.sub(r'(\w+)', r'`\1`', exp)
).reset_index(name='FinalVal')
```

---

Setup and imports used:

```py
import re

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Patient': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    'ID': ['72', 'SD75', '74', '74', '71', '72']
})
```

Comment: I really like this approach but wondering Is this still efficient if my patients are about 1.2 million and the distinct ID's are about 6000 ?

Comment: More time efficient than iterating certainly, but not more space efficient. The question is do you have to space to support 1.2m x 6k indicator DataFrame. `eval` is slower than converting to an actual computation like `indicator_df ['71'] + indicator_df['72']` etc. However, I left it this way to be completely dependent on the `exp`.

Comment: That Makes total sense! This solved 80% of what I am looking for but I am not able to parse mutiple expressions dynamically to get my desired result. I have created another question for that problem , if you can kindly take a look and point me in the right direction, I'd be highly obiliged. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69413841/evaluating-a-data-frame-through-another-indicator-data-frame

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to parse that expression and evaluate it. Instead, I would create [dummy or indicator variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_variable_(statistics)) for the `ID` column. (Indicator variables are also called one-hot encoded variables.) With these indicators, you can then calculate your expression using a standard function.

Here's how to do it with Pandas and scikit-learn. I am using scikit-learn's [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder). An alternative might be Panda's [`get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html), but the OneHotEncoder allows you to specify the categories.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

variables = [71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, "SD75", "SD76"]
enc = OneHotEncoder(categories=[variables], sparse=False)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Patient": ["A"] * 4 + ["B", "C"],
    "ID": [72, "SD75", 74, 74, 71, 72]
})
# Create one-hot encoded variables, also called dummy or indicator variables
df_one_hot = pd.DataFrame(
    enc.fit_transform(df[["ID"]]),
    columns=variables,
    index=df.Patient
)

# Aggregate dummy or one-hot variables, so there's one for each patient
# You may need to alter the aggretaion function
# I chose max because it matched your example
# but perhaps sum might be better (e.g. patient A has two entires for 74, should that be a value of 2 for variable 74?
one_hot_patient = df_one_hot.groupby(level="Patient").agg(max)

# Finally, evaluate your expression
# Create a function to calcualte the output given a data frame
def my_expr(DF):
    out = (DF[71] + DF[72]) \
        * (DF[73] + DF[75] + DF["SD75"]) \
        * (DF[74]+DF[76]+DF["SD76"])
    return out
    
output = one_hot_patient.assign(FinalVal=my_expr)
```

Result

```
          71   72   73   74   75   76  SD75  SD76  FinalVal
Patient
A        0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0   1.0   0.0       1.0
B        1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0
C        0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0   0.0   0.0       0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sub instead of replace should work:

```
for j in mylist:
    if j in new_dfl:
        exp = re.sub(r'\b{}'.format(j), '1', exp)
    else:
        exp = re.sub(r'\b{}'.format(j), '0', exp)
```

Another way that would work for this exact scenario is to sort *mylist* in descending order so the items preceded by *SD* are iterated before the others.

```
mylist = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', exp).split()   
mylist.sort(reverse=True)
```

Comment: edited previous answer to include another option.